# how to display selected data from json object

Tags: angularjs, json, cordova

When i run this function, i got a JSON object as shown in figure
i just want to display only a selected parameter, say username.

```
 [displaying json object on running this function][1] 

$scope.signUp = function () {
    $http({
        method: "post",
        dataType:'json',
        url: "http://192.168.0.60/api/Customer/CustomerLoginService",
        crossDomain : true,
        data: {
            'username': $scope.username,
            'password': $scope.password,
             'entrytoken': $scope.entrytoken               
        },
     headers: { 'Accept':' text/plain','Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).then(function success(data) {
        alert("success function");
       var obj=JSON.stringify(data);
       alert(obj);                 
   });
```

[image]

how can i display a singe parameter.

Comment: you don't need to stringify data, just do data.username

Comment: @Lekens That gives an output as undefined

Comment: do this to inspect the element in the json,....console.log('DATA=',data); open the console to view your data maybe username exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
then(function success(data) {        
       alert(data.data.username);
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(obj.data.username);
```

The object properties can be access just like any normal object.
In the future though, there is no need to stringify the return.

Comment: It gives an undefined output

Comment: what is the output if you just alert 'obj'?

Comment: try alert(obj.data.username);

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj glad you found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
headers: { 'Accept':' text/plain','Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).then(function success(data) {
        alert("success function");
      // var obj=JSON.stringify(data);
       console.log('DATA=',data);
```

This will allow you to check if username exist in the data return as response. Open your browser console to view the data. please use google chrome